# Running GitLab CI job after a specific stage without waiting for manual trigger

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a pipeline that's similar to this:

```yaml
stages:
  - test
  - assemble
  - deploy
  - report

deploy:development:
  environment: development
  resource_group: deployment
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  script:
    - ./deploy.sh
  stage: deploy

deploy:production:
  environment: production
  resource_group: deployment
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual
  script:
    - ./deploy.sh
  stage: deploy

report:sonarqube:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  script:
    - ./gradlew sonar
  stage: report
```

The pipeline contains multiple stages, including `deploy:development` and `deploy:production`.

The `report:sonarqube` job is currently set to run after `deploy:production`, but I would like it to execute immediately after `deploy:development`, without waiting for the *manual* trigger from `deploy:production`. However, `deploy:production` should still be a *manual* trigger and should cause the pipeline to fail — if it fails.

I've considered using `allow_failure: true`, but that's not ideal since `deploy:production` should not fail, and a failure in `deploy:production` should result in the entire pipeline failing.

Any suggestions on how to configure the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file or adjust the pipeline configuration to achieve this desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

```
deploy:production:
  environment: production
  resource_group: deployment
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  script:
    - ./deploy.sh
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
```

you can try this